# Similar arrayformula working, non-array formula working, why not this arrayformula?

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This arrayformula works in my spreadsheet:

```
=arrayformula(IF(A3:A<>"", DATEDIF(H3:H,"01/01/21","m"), ""))
```

This non-array is working:

```
=DATEDIF(MAX(datevalue(H3), "1/1/2021"),"01/01/22","m")
```

So I would think this would work as an arrayformula version of the working non-array:

```
=arrayformula(IF(A3:A<>"", DATEDIF(MAX(datevalue(H3:H), "1/1/2021"),"01/01/22","m"), ""))
```

Instead, I get this error:

> DATEVALUE parameter '' cannot be parsed to date/time.

Can anyone please point me to what I might be doing wrong? Or why this arrayformula won't work?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Shared version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qkv-XoY9GA8lKuPty27_SZn1xrwjl22YnOg9mOYzovI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following:

```
=arrayformula(IF(A3:A<>"", DATEDIF(MAX((H3:H), "1/1/2021"),"01/01/22","m"), ""))
```

Comment: That did it, thank you.  So it looks like the one difference is the removal of the date value parameter on H2:H. Is that correct?

Comment: *"That did it, thank you. So it looks like the one difference is the removal of the date value parameter on H2:H. Is that correct?"*. Correct. Though my solution answers your question to the dot (*"...why **this** arrayformula won't work?"*) you accepted an alternative... Oh well. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A<>"", DATEDIF(MAX(H2:H, "1/1/2021"), "1/1/2022", "m"), ))
```

Comment: This one works as well. Thank you. Index is a function I am always a bit confused by, but I cansee this functioning in my spreadsheet.

Comment: Can anyone share what the benefit of using the arrayformula as opposed to using the index?

Comment: index is type of arrayformula. benefit in this case: its shorter.